# load hover pic in first load page

Tags: html, css

i have div with this code

style

```
#input{background:url(../image/main.png)}
#input:hover {background:url(../image/hover.png)}
```

html

```
<div id="input">input div </div>
<div id="input">input div 2</div>
<div id="input">input div 3</div>
<div id="input">input div 4</div>
```

when page load main.png load and show but when mouse on div first div black and after 2 or 3 second hover.png show . my background pic size isnt big but maybe host is very weak anyway for load two pic first time and hover pic show fast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sprites for that and then set your background with `background-position` so this way everything will load at first time.

And the best thing about sprites that it actually makes your load time faster because each image requires separate request to the server but if you request just a single file for most of the website you can increase loading time dramatically.

This is a good example how it looks:

[image]

And the code wold be something like:

```
.mydiv:hover{
   background-position:-30px 0px;
}
```

[Live example of how sprites works](http://jsfiddle.net/4qHGw/)

For further reading on how `background-positions` actually works please take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: give me a second, i will make jsfiddle

Comment: @behzadn Yes, you would join images together.

Comment: but any browsers havent the same scale . for exaple 30px in firefox show right and only main section but in ie 30 px show main and some section hover ?

Comment: @behzadn are you referring to my live example? Every modern browser including most of IE versions supports `background-position` so you have cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Did you see the second picture in the first load an invisible coating can then be loaded more quickly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19829/discussion-between-linas-and-behzad-n)